# Facebook me/admined_groups returning empty data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a piece of code able to send messages, albums and so on, on pages and groups on Facebook.
When I perform a request like:

```
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/accounts' );
```

I get details about all the pages I managed, so with their access_token and I can write on them. Perfect.

But when I try:

```
 $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/admined_groups' );
```

I get back an empty record. When I try directly with the Graph Api Explorer, so with https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me/admined_groups, I get the list of the groups I managed.

When I analyse my FBToken using Access Token Info, I see I have "user_managed_groups, manage_pages, publish_pages, publish_actions, public_profile"

So, how can I get the list of groups using /me/admined_groups ? (and the Token to post on the group). Is it still possible?

Comment: What API version are you using?

Comment: me/admined_groups with a User access token with user_managed_groups permissions granted should be enough. So as far as I see your call should work. Maybe you're using a page access token?